# kill() is destroying my parent process

Tags: c, posix, ipc, signals, kill

I want my child process to send a signal to the parent process without destroying it. The only way I know to send a signal is to use kill(getppid(),SIGUSR1), however this is killing my parent process. How do I send a signal without killing it? I'm using a signal handler which runs but once it finishes, the parent process is killed. I would like to continue where I left off.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is killing your parent process because you're not installing a signal handler for `SIGUSR1` in it.

Comment: No I do have a signal handler that I use. But it seems to run the signal handler then kill the process.

Comment: @user1103966 Show some code. Show the handler and how you install it.